# Laravel controller name should be plural or singular?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, naming-conventions

What is the naming convention in Laravel for controllers? They should be singular or plural. I saw some people use singular and some people use plural for that. What is the correct form?

Comment: it is your choice, there is no actual convention for controller naming

Answer (score 60, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions) is a list of **naming conventions** accepted by **Laravel community**. According to this, **Controller** name should be **Singular** although you could chose your own convention as your need or how your team prefer.

Comment: [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers) in laravel document also use singular for Controller

Answer (score 14):

You should follow those naming convention:

1. Model Name should be singular e.g: '**Profile**', not 'Profiles'
2. Controller name should be singular with 'Controller' suffix e.g:
   '**ProfileController**', not 'ProfilesController'
3. Php class Name should be in 'StudlyCase' format e.g: '**TestClass**'
4. Php function Name should be in 'camelCase' format e.g:
   '**testFunction**'
5. Class constants MUST be declared in all upper case with underscore
   separators; for example:

   ```
   class Foo
   {
       const VERSION = '1.0';
       const DATE_APPROVED = '2012-06-01';
   }
   ```

**Useful link:**

https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/

Answer (score 1):

Plural. Although the official laravel docs use singular for controller names, it is very well known that most of prominent laravel developers such as Jeffrey Way, Adam Wathan, Chris Fidao and many others uses plural for controller names that it sort of become the actual standard.

You are far better off using plural so you feel less confusion when you watch their videos, read their blog posts.etc

Comment: This is actually a very good point. I'm not sure why Laracasts uses plurals, but it can throw a new user watching those tutorials. In the end it's best to pick one route and remain consistent.