# Laravel Controller name in singular or plural?

Tags: php, laravel

In a tutorial on Laravel (*1) it is said that the controller name should be plural instead of singular. I am surprised because Laravel always generates the controller automatically in singular. There was also the question in 2018 in the Laravel Context here in the SO (*2). Has anything changed here in this regard? Is there a general valid statement here or is this a matter of taste. For me personally, singular makes total sense.

*1 https://youtu.be/L1owEfA9ioc?t=148

*2 [laravel controller name should be plural or singular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48031176/laravel-controller-name-should-be-plural-or-singular)

Comment: should be in singular

Comment: Funny that you already have found another question asking the exact same thing. [laravel controller name should be plural or singular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48031176/laravel-controller-name-should-be-plural-or-singular)

Comment: Singular also makes sense to me. The fact that Laravel, now in its 9th version, automatically creates the controller in singular alone is an indication for me that singular is the right way to go.

Comment: @N69S I deliberately shared the link you shared here in my question. So I did research before I asked the question.

Comment: @MaxPattern and that question already had an answer. you could have commented for an update or checked the comments.

Comment: @N69S Now i understood! Thx. But unfortunately I can no longer delete my question. Far be it from me to repeat an already existing question here. My primary concern was whether anything has changed since 2018 (a book on naming conventions that can be referred to, etc.).  In future, I will post it as a comment in the existing question. With the hope that my question will be answered quickly in the comment. Thanks to you and have a nice start of the week!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Laravel community has agreed upon the [following list of naming](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions) conventions. This states that the name of the controller **should be singular**, while you are **free to choose another** convention if it suits your needs or the preferences of your team.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Exactly what i expected. It shoul be singular. The author from the Youtube Tutorial give my only the answer: "According to Laravel controllers should be plural :)" That is the reasob why i ask our community here. MErci and +1

Comment: Would appreciate it if accepted.

Comment: Im appreciate to accept! Have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 0):

In a single sentence? **It should be singular**. because Laravel has its own way of doing things. If you type `PHP artisan make:model Todo -a` you'll be able to see that Laravel creates everything as singular except migrations. why? because there will be multiple items on a table.

`php artisan stub:publish` will get you the templates of all the component which you can customize although i don't recommend it meddling with it if you're a beginner.